# jQuery IF this OR that

Tags: jquery, if-statement

can someone help me out with what I'm doing wrong here:

```
if ($('.c-user-name a span:contains("User 1")') || $('.c-user-name a span:contains("User 2")')) {
    $('#admin-links').css('display', 'block');
};
```

Basically, I'm trying to change CSS if a specific user is logged in.

Also, if there's a better way of doing this, I'd love to know. We may have more than 2 users that need this and the condition could get quite long!

Comment: You should consider something server side like PHP to do this, on client side its easily spoofable, anyone could open dev tools and set `#admin-links` to `display: block;` irrespective of user role

Comment: A jQuery object is always truthy. `:contains` is a selector, so you're selecting `span`s that contain that text, not requesting a Boolean true or false.

Comment: Use toggle too... `const user = $('.c-user-name a span:contains("User 1")').length===1 || $('.c-user-name a span:contains("User 2")').length===1;
    $('#admin-links').toggle(user);
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of the JQuery object to see if any element exists:

```
if ($('.c-user-name a span:contains("User 1")').length || $('.c-user-name a span:contains("User 2")').length) {
   $('#admin-links').css('display', 'block');
};
```

A more readable approach would be using `is`:

```
   if ($('.c-user-name a span').is(':contains("User 1")')
```

Comment: .length worked a treat. Thank you! I like the more readable approach also but is it possible to have an array of usernames?